# Excel VBA: mysterious shift of pictures

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a list of members and use the following code to add member photos. The code works to add photos but the position of the photos sometimes shift for no apparent reason. The photos are supposed to be added to the upper-left corner of each record. When it's not working, the photos shift progressively downward and eventually cross into the next record (see screenshot). I have recorded the top position (p.top) of the photos and compare the one that's not shifting with the one that's shifting. What I found is they are identical. In other words, the top position of the photos that shift downward is identical to the top position of the photos that don't shift. If top positions are identical, shouldn't the photos appear at the same position and not shift?

```
Sub add_PHOTO()
'add photo to file
 Dim p As Shape
Dim record_num As Long
'    Dim LOGO_Path_Prefix As String
Const PHOTO_Path_Prefix1 = "D:\test1\"
Const PHOTO_Path_Prefix2 = "D:\test2\"
Const LOGO_Path_Prefix = "D:\test3\"
Dim Actual_PHOTO_Path As String  'the actual string used for the path of the photo
Dim Total_Record_Num As Long
Const Photo_Width = 161
Const Photo_Height = 190
Const vOffset = 2.5 
Const hOffset = 2   

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Total_Record_Num = Workbooks("test.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Pictures.Delete
For Each p In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes
    p.Delete
Next

'Total_Record_Num = Workbooks("test.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    On Error Resume Next

    For record_num = 0 To Total_Record_Num Step 1
        'insert photo
        'check if photo exists
        If Len(.Range("C" & record_num * Rows_Per_Record + 1)) <> 0 Then
            
            'find the path for the photo
            If Len(Dir(PHOTO_Path_Prefix1 & .Range("C" & record_num * Rows_Per_Record + 1) & ".png", vbNormal)) <> 0 Then
                Actual_PHOTO_Path = PHOTO_Path_Prefix1
            ElseIf Len(Dir(PHOTO_Path_Prefix2 & .Range("C" & record_num * Rows_Per_Record + 1) & ".png", vbNormal)) <> 0 Then
                Actual_PHOTO_Path = PHOTO_Path_Prefix2
            End If
        
            Set p = .Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=Actual_PHOTO_Path & .Range("C" & record_num * Rows_Per_Record + 1) _
                & ".png", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Left:=.Cells(record_num * Rows_Per_Record + 6, 1).Left + hOffset, _
                Top:=.Cells(record_num * Rows_Per_Record + 1, 1).Top + vOffset, Width:=Photo_Width, Height:=Photo_Height)

' record position of photos

            Workbooks("test.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(record_num + 1, 1) = record_num + 1
            Workbooks("test.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(record_num + 1, 2) = .Cells(record_num + 1, 1).Address
            Workbooks("test.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(record_num + 1, 3) = .Cells(record_num * Rows_Per_Record + 1, 1).Top + vOffset
            Workbooks("test.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(record_num + 1, 4) = p.Top
            Workbooks("test.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(record_num + 1, 5) = .Range("C" & record_num * Rows_Per_Record + 1).Text
            Set p = Nothing 

snipped
```

[image: photo top]

photos not shifting ================= photos shifting

[image: working]
[image: between frames]

Comment: In short, Excel is not really the right tool for this.

Comment: @braX Maybe, but it can do it. I have been using Excel to send photo quotes to customers for years, never experiencing this problem.

Comment: There could be hidden rows or some irregularities in the height of some of your rows at a certain point.

Comment: @DecimalTurn Thanks for the comment. Row heights are set by the same VBA script and there are no hidden rows. Some records don't have pictures. I believe all these cannot explain why pictures shift. My point is if photos have the same top position, they should appear at the same vertical place. Not in my case. I even wrote a script to extract the p.top and found that, same as before, p.top of shifted picture is identical to that of not shifted picture. p.top doesn't dictate the vertical position of pictures anymore.

Comment: How do you get those unshifted pictures to compare with the shifted ones?

Comment: @DecimalTurn Sometimes, pictures are not shifted, other times, they are. I can't tell when they'll shift and when won't. The above script stores p.top on a sheet. I manually copied the data to an unused area on that sheet. This way, I have p.top for both shifted and unshifted. As shown in the above picture, one has a yellow background. The other doesn't. It doesn't matter which one is shifted and which one is not shifted because both data are identical.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this bug on my end. Could you provide a [Minimal Complete Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and specify the version of Excel you are using?

Comment: @DecimalTurn Thanks for spending time working on my problem. There is a total of 10 subs in this module. It reads data from another workbook and picture files from disk. It'd not be so easy to edit them to give a working module for someone to work with. Let me see how to do it. As the problem happens only some of the time but not all of the time, I can't say it's reproducible.

Comment: @DecimalTurn I might be able to reduce them down to 2 subs. I'm working on it.